# Starting a rails server in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

I have created a new rails project with the command:

```
rails project_name
```

but now in that project if I run:

```
rails server
```

I just creates a new project call server, it doesn't start webrick.

How do I start the server and get rails running?

Comment: Actually guys, if I do a -v to see which version of rails I have it says 3.0.3. But if I run script/server it's works and says it's version 2. What the hell's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing Rails 2 and Rails 3 commands. By the looks of it, you're using Rails 2, which means starting the server would be `script/server`, not `rails server`

Comment: If that's the case then you would've needed to use `rails new new_project` to create the project. The `rails new_project` syntax has been removed since all the old script/* commands have been moved into the rails command. Double-check with `rails -v`

Comment: @Smickie I wouldn't be so sure, type rails -v to find out.

Comment: Actually guys, if I do a -v to see which version of rails I have it says 3.0.3. But if I run script/server it's works and says it's version 2. What the hell's going on.

Comment: If script/server even exists, it means it's a Rails 2 app. It means you've got rails 3 installed but the app needs upgrading.

Comment: For me, neither `rails server` nor `rails script/server` start webrick. `rails -v` outputs `Rails 2.3.14`, how can I start webrick?

Comment: In Rails 2 and below, it's just `script/server`, not `rails script/server`

Comment: `script/server` outputs `-bash: script/server: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 6):

Old versions or rails are bugging you. Deinstall them using `gem uninstall rails`. I recommend using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) with gemsets to create separate environments for each project.

Answer (score 1):

Step by Step rails server Installation :

1. Create Gemset using " rvm create gemset "
2. rails new
3. goto rails app directory "cd/"
4. gem install rails
5. echo "rvm use " > .rvmrc 
   for example : echo "rvm use 1.9.3-p385@mygemset" > .rvmrc
6. run - "bundle install"
7. rails s

yeah, nothing to do more... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu and found that I had rails 3 installed with gem and rails 2 installed with apt.  Removing the apt version solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove rails
```